# How do I continuously refresh scrollview screens in Kivy?

Tags: python, button, kivy, scrollview, clock

I've recently downloaded Kivy for a uni project and it turns out to be exactly what I am looking for.

I am trying to build a collection of scrollview screens that all feature the same collection of clickable buttons. Once a button on the current screen is pressed, the screen manager switches to the next one, where all previous buttons, except the one(s) previously pressed are displayed. [image: This picture] outlines what I am trying to do in a simple manner.

My current approach to keep track of the button states is to incorporate an array of 1's and 0's (0 = unpressed, 1 = pressed), and update it once a button is fired. The next screen then only loads the button if its corresponding array element is = 0.

And there lies my problem - all screens are initialised only once, in the beginning, and not continuously. I have tried to use `clock.schedule_interval` to continuously refresh the screens, but I get the error that "scrollview only accepts one widget".

I'm sure there's an obvious solution here that I am not seeing. Can you help me out?

Here's a simple version of my code:

```
import kivy

from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView

from kivy.clock import Clock

import numpy as np
drug_state = np.zeros (2)

class screen_A (Screen):

    view = ObjectProperty(None)


    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(screen_A, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.create_scrollview)    // Replacing with clock.schedule_interval yields exception "scrollview accepts only one widget"


    def jump_to_screen_B (self, instance):
        Athena_app.screen_manager.current = 'Screen_B'


    def update_button_A (self, instance):
        global drug_state
        drug_state [0] = 1

    def update_button_B (self, instance):
        global drug_state
        drug_state [1] = 1


    def create_scrollview(self, dt):

        global drug_state

        layout = GridLayout (cols = 2, spacing = 10, size_hint_y = None)
        layout.bind (minimum_height = layout.setter ("height"))


        if drug_state [0] == 0:
            self.A = Button (text = "Button A", size=(50, 50), size_hint=(1, None), background_color=(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1), color=(1, 1, 1, 1))
            self.A.bind (on_press = self.update_button_A)
            self.A.bind (on_press = self.jump_to_screen_B)
            layout.add_widget (self.A)

        if drug_state [1] == 0:
            self.B = Button (text = "Button B", size=(50, 50), size_hint=(1, None), background_color=(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1), color=(1, 1, 1, 1))
            self.B.bind (on_press = self.update_button_B)
            self.B.bind (on_press = self.jump_to_screen_B)
            layout.add_widget (self.B)


        scrollview = ScrollView(size_hint=(1, None), size=(Window.width, Window.height))
        scrollview.add_widget(layout)
        self.view.add_widget(scrollview)


Builder.load_file("screen_A.kv")


class screen_B (Screen):

    view = ObjectProperty(None)


    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(screen_B, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.create_scrollview)        // Replacing with clock.schedule_interval yields exception "scrollview accepts only one widget"


    def jump_to_screen_A (self, instance):
        Athena_app.screen_manager.current = 'Screen_A'


    def create_scrollview(self, dt):

        global drug_state

        layout = GridLayout (cols = 2, spacing = 10, size_hint_y = None)
        layout.bind (minimum_height = layout.setter ("height"))


        if drug_state [0] == 0:
            self.A = Button (text = "Button A", size=(50, 50), size_hint=(1, None), background_color=(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1), color=(1, 1, 1, 1))
            layout.add_widget (self.A)

        if drug_state [1] == 0:
            self.B = Button (text = "Button B", size=(50, 50), size_hint=(1, None), background_color=(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1), color=(1, 1, 1, 1))
            layout.add_widget (self.B)


        self.back_to_feedstock = Button (text = "Back", size=(50, 50), size_hint=(1, None), background_color=(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1), color=(1, 1, 1, 1))
        self.back_to_feedstock.bind (on_press = self.jump_to_screen_A)
        layout.add_widget (self.back_to_feedstock)


        scrollview = ScrollView(size_hint=(1, None), size=(Window.width, Window.height))
        scrollview.add_widget(layout)
        self.view.add_widget(scrollview)


Builder.load_file("screen_B.kv")


class LoremIpsum(App):

    def build(self):
        self.screen_manager = ScreenManager()

        self.screen_a = screen_A()
        screen = Screen (name = 'Screen_A')
        screen.add_widget (self.screen_a)
        self.screen_manager.add_widget (screen)

        self.screen_b = screen_B()
        screen = Screen (name = 'Screen_B')
        screen.add_widget (self.screen_b)
        self.screen_manager.add_widget (screen)

        return self.screen_manager


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Athena_app = LoremIpsum()
    Athena_app.run()
```

The builder files are the same, they just differ in what they display for "Button":

```
#:kivy 1.11.0

<AppScreenManager>:
    screen_A:

<screen_A>:
    view: view

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        BoxLayout:
            size: (64, 64)
            size_hint: (1, None)

            Button:
                text: "Select Option A"
                color: (1, 1, 1, 1)
                background_color: (.3, .3, .3, 1)

        ScrollView:
            id: view
```

Comment: I don't think constantly refreshing the `ScrollView` is the right approach. Write some code to remove the `Button` from the `ScrollView`, and bind that code to the `Button`. That should work. You can even define your own `Button` extension class that has a `pressed` attribute (rather than using a separate array).